# Missing values handling in LightGBM

Tags: missing-data, lightgbm, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I'm a bit confused about the handling of missing data by LightGBM. I'm using the R package but my question should not be language-specific.

In a regression setting with no categorical feature, I have a dataset containing missing values (represented by `NA`s) in both features and the target variable. The target variable also contains zeros which are not to be considered as missing, but legitimate zeros.

Reading the first answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/81846/handling-missing-values-for-lightgbm-model) and [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2921), I understand that the default behavior for missing values in features is

(1)

> numericals are assigned to the side of the ongoing split that most reduces the loss

However, what about the missing values in the target variable? Running a few tests, I came to the conclusion that they are replaced by zeros, which is a rather dangerous behavior without warning.

Reading [this documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Advanced-Topics.html), the default is `zero_as_missing=false`, which means that

(2)

> the unrecorded values in sparse matrices (and LightSVM) are treated as
> zeros

So I understand that NA's (in both features and target) are replaced by zeros. Isn't it in contradiction with the quotation (1)?

If we set `zero_as_missing=true`, then

(3)

> NA and zeros (including unrecorded values in sparse matrices (and
> LightSVM)) are treated as missing

I understand that both zeros and NAs are considered missing and treated as in (1). But

1. What if I don't want zeros to be treated as missing?
2. Isn't it the default behavior according to the first link?

Can you explain, for both `zero_as_missing` options, for features and target, what happens to missing values during training?

Of course the easy way to go would be to pass a `drop_na` to the entire dataset but it's not satisfying.

**EDIT**  It seems that LightGBM is indeed replacing NA's in the target by zeros: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/4483, and I agree that there should be a warning. However I'm still not sure about what the documentation is saying.